# in ckEditor (wysiwyg) how to set the default clicked button

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

Upon execution of the ckEditor I want a particular button be already clicked (programmatically).
For example i want the button blockquote be already clicked:
[image] 
 so that when the user opens the ckEditor that function related to blockquote button is already fired. I saw it somewhere, but I don't remember it. It was something like

```
 dialoge.click ='blockquote ' or something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Config.js add the following:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady',function(ev) {
            ev.editor.execCommand( 'blockquote' );
        } );
```

note:
The command is always in lower case. It's 'blockquote' or 'bulletedlist' rather than 'BlackQuote' or 'BulletedList'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.execCommand( 'blockquote' );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: This is an initialization code for textarea-based editor instance. I guess that you're using such thing, don't you?